# Caps LOCk DElay Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, capslock

This issue hasn't been mentioned.

Investigating further, using this script listed here

[Caps Lock delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574740/caps-lock-delay)

was able to fix the issue on Ubuntu 17.04 but on 17.10 I get this error in the TERminal

```
Could not load keyboard geometry for :0
              BadName (named color or font does not exist)
              Resulting keymap file will not describe geometry
```

Can't find a single workaround online for 17.10, and it's frustrating because the OS is almost unusable as, obviously, typing is a major part of using the computer. SHift is not an option at the moment.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Edit: After thorough investigation, the issue lies in the standard input stream, stdin. 
NOT REPRODUCIBLE in recovery mode, the .sh fix works fine.

Will continue to look through shortly.

**Edit: After FURTHER analysis, the script in the first link appears to work on some distros, and using the startup application and chmod +x'ing it I was able to execute it upon multiple reboots, 
Others such as standard Ubuntu have a kernel patch, which I don't know how to implement**

Any distro that's based off Gnome, the script works successfully, others tested under my scope were Lubuntu and Ubuntu Budgie.