# Pressing caps lock (to return to lower case) doesn't always register

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I've noticed on Ubuntu my Logitech keyboard doesn't seem to always register pressing cap-locks a second time (to return to lower case) so I end up typing this:

```
UBuntu
LOgitech
```

I'm sure it never happened on Windows 7.

Anyone know a fix? It's rather annoying.

Comment: Keystrokes are about as low level as it gets. It's very unlikely that any software causes this issue which makes it unlikely you can fix the problem with software.  Have you tried this with another keyboard? Are you absolutely sure that they keys are pressed in the correct sequence. For example, are you able to replicate the behavior when you type slowly, or does it only occur when you are typing quickly? Are you really using the caps lock key to key a single capital letter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caps Lock delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574740/caps-lock-delay)

Comment: @MartinThornton many thanks